# Почему не совпадают границы ячеек таблицы HTML с линиями клеточного фона CSS?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Не могу понять почему не совпадают границы таблицы HTML с линиями клеточного фона CSS. В чём подвох?

Вот так выглядит в Хроме последней версии (Чёрные линии - это границы таблицы, более светлые - линии фона на CSS.):
[image: Скриншот]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

table {
  margin: 70px auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: linear-gradient( #bbb, transparent 1px), linear-gradient( 90deg, #bbb, transparent 1px);
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-position: -1px 1px;
}

td,
th {
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно лучше подойдет реализация через тени, они предоставляют больше пространства для действий.

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #000000 inset;
```

Но самое простое решение проблемы это изменить алгоритм расчета ширины элементов. Чтобы рамка не увеличивала элементы для этого добавьте свойство

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

элементам td, th

```
td,
th {
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

И будет Вам счастье.

```css
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    table {
      margin: 70px auto;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      background: linear-gradient( #bbb, transparent 1px), linear-gradient( 
90deg, #bbb, transparent 1px);
      background-size: 20px 20px;
      background-position: -1px 1px;
    }

   td,
   th {
      width: 120px;
      height: 60px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

border: 1px solid black; - это свойство увеличивает ширину и высоту на 2 пикселя (1 пиксель левая граница и 1 пиксель правая граница) по длине и аналогично по высоте. Возможно, дело в этом. Вместо border сделай outline и разверни на всю страницу. У меня всё сошлось.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

table {
  margin: 70px auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: linear-gradient( #bbb, transparent 1px), linear-gradient( 90deg, #bbb, transparent 1px);
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-position: -1px 1px;
}

td,
th {
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Проблема решена.